# Microsoft Graph API to overwrite/delete permission for drive items

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is there any way to overwrite permission to share drive item to specific users only?

e.g.
Case 1:
File1 is shared with User1. I want to share File1 to User2 only using graph api which can also remove User1 from share list.

Currently, Graph APIs are available to add the permission and to delete permission separately.
But, I need to deal with a lot of files to update the permissions and for each file I need to take difference of permissions (User list already shared and User list needs to be updated to share item) for drive item to delete the permission to remove User from share list.

Case 2:
Another case is to make File private to the user. Is there any way to make file private directly(possibly single api call)?. Currently, I have to delete each user permission from shared list(5 calls to delete permissions if file is shared with 5 users). Again, I am dealing with a lot of files.

[Edited]
More info: My use case is for Direct Access permission and Not link-based permission.

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario, I think you  can create a sharelink for a file by using the following API: /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink and grant access to sharelink accordingly.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on accessing shared drive items.

If this doesn't help, consider raising [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific scenario so that it goes into our backlog.

Comment: Thank you. But, I forgot to mention my use case is for direct access permission and not link-based permission. I have updated the question.

Comment: @JigarT Have you tried leveraging batching to see if this helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

Comment: Yes, batch can work but currently our arch is to deal with one file and all its related operations at a time. One of that operation is to delete permission. All this operation is already being done in batch only. Also, as per the MS guidelines, batch should not send more than 20 request at a time.